# Remove lvds and use external monitor

Tags: windows-8, laptop, external-display, laptop-display

My laptop hinges recently broke off and I wish to use my laptop sort of like media player connected to a TV. For now, I can just switch to external VGA display after the OS boots.

I want to remove the entire display panel and keep just the base of the laptop as the current configuration looks ugly. So, if I remove the lvds cable from the motherboard, remove the whole lcd panel, and power on the laptop with external display connected, will my laptop detect the new configuration and route the video signals to external monitor?

I could have just used start+p to change the second screen settings after boot but I want to make sure that if in future I need to format my laptop, I can still see the display.

BTW I am using Windows 8 x64 Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wanted to use this, there was no other choice for me but to go ahead and see it for myself.

I opened the laptop and disconnected 5 cables - lvds, mic, webcam and a couple of them acting as wifi antennas. After assembling the base back, I connected the VGA cable to the laptop and powered it on (fingers crossed). Voila!! the OS took the external monitor as the default one and routed all video signals to it without any change in display configuration.

My only complaint would be that external monitors are slow to respond to the video signals during POST, so it normally skips the initial part where the laptop manufacturer's logo is displayed, with options to halt the normal start-up. But I can still get into BIOS and change settings and do all the pre-boot stuff I want to since I know the keys reserved for each specific function.